# JMH - Setting "lines" parameter for "stack" profiler programmatically

Tags: java, jmh

In JMH StackProfiler.class accepts several parameters: "lines", "top", "detailLine", etc.

On command line one can define parameter values this way:

```
java -jar my-benchmarks.jar -prof stack -jvmArgsAppend -Djmh.stack.lines=3
```

- Is there a programmatic way to provide the values?

Seemingly obvious

```
new OptionsBuilder().addProfiler("stack").jvmArgsAppend("-Djmh.stack.lines=3")
```

or

```
@Fork(jvmArgsAppend="-Djmh.stack.lines=3")
```

or

```
System.setProperty("jmh.stack.lines", "3");
...
new Runner(opt).run();
```

did not result in desirable effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be using a very old JMH, because stack profiler already accepts options:

```
$ java -jar jmh-samples/target/benchmarks.jar -prof stack:help
Usage: -prof <profiler-name>:opt1=value1,value2;opt2=value3

Options accepted by org.openjdk.jmh.profile.StackProfiler:

[...]

  lines=<int>  Number of stack lines to save in each stack trace. 
               Larger values provide more insight into who is 
               calling the top stack method, as the expense of more
               stack trace shapes to collect. (default: [1]) 

[...]
```

There is no way to access this from annotations, but Java API accepts the profiler options string:

```
/**
 * Add the profiler in the run
 * @param profiler profiler class
 * @param initLine profiler options initialization line
 * @return builder
 */
ChainedOptionsBuilder addProfiler(Class<? extends Profiler> profiler,
                                  String initLine);

/**
 * Add the profiler in the run
 * @param profiler profiler class name, or profiler alias
 * @param initLine profiler options initialization line
 * @return builder
 */
ChainedOptionsBuilder addProfiler(String profiler, String initLine);
```

So, something like this should work:

```
.addProfiler("stack", "lines=3")
```

Comment: To try the command line option I was indeed using a very old version. I blindly copied mvn archetype:generate .. -Dversion=1.0 to generate a new JMH project.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I should've read the javadoc :)